# What does OGR stand for?

Tags: ogr

There are numerous commands and libraries that I see referenced or prefixed with OGR. What does the OGR stand for?

- `ogrinfo`
- `ogr2ogr`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

OpenGIS Simple Features Reference Implementation. You can read a short statement about the history of the abbreviation among some other GDAL related facts in the [GDAL FAQ](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQGeneral#WhatdoesOGRstandfor). The relevant paragraph states:

> OGR used to stand for OpenGIS Simple Features Reference Implementation. However, since OGR is not fully compliant with the OpenGIS Simple Feature specification and is not approved as a reference implementation of the spec the name was changed to OGR Simple Features Library. The only meaning of OGR in this name is historical. OGR is also the prefix used everywhere in the source of the library for class names, filenames, etc.